# How can I change LED's brightness with PWM and USART in USART1_IRQHandler?

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery, adc, pwm, usart

I am using STM32F4 discovery board and I am working on changing LED brightness and timer period using ADC and USART.

I use DMA to fetch ADC values, selected TIM4 for PWM and selected USART1 for USART. ADC, USART and PWM are working well so far, but `USART1_IRQHandler()` is not working as expected.

How can I adjust timer period and LED brightness with PWM and ADC in the following implementation of `USART1_IRQHandler()`?

```
void USART1_IRQHandler()
{
   if (USART_GetITStatus(USART1, USART_IT_RXNE) )
    {      
      delay(168000);
        i = USART_ReceiveData(USART1);
        if(i == '1'){

          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC1Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          UARTSend("3 led aktif\r\n",sizeof("LED 4 ON\r\n"));    
        }
        else if(i == '2')
        {
          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC1Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC2Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC2PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          UARTSend("2 led aktif\r\n",sizeof("LED 4 ON\r\n"));  

        }
        else if(i == '4')
        {

          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC1Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC2Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC2PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC3Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC3PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          UARTSend("4 led aktif\r\n",sizeof("LED 4 ON\r\n"));  

        }
        else if(i == '4')
          {
          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC1Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC1PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC2Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC2PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC3Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC3PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          TIMOC_InitStruct.TIM_Pulse=pwm_value;
          TIM_OC4Init(TIM4,&TIMOC_InitStruct);
          TIM_OC4PreloadConfig(TIM4,TIM_OCPreload_Enable);

          UARTSend("4 led aktif\r\n",sizeof("LED 4 ON\r\n"));        
        }
         else 
         {
           Hello();  
           UARTSend("Please enter another number:\n",sizeof("Please enter another number:\n"));
         }   
    } USART_ClearITPendingBit(USART1,USART_IT_RXNE);
}
```

Comment: I submitted an edit suggestion - you should keep both Q&A and code sample identifiers in English, so I replaced some Turkish wording I found. I don't speak Turkish, but Google Translator does... :)   - Please re-check that the translations are OK.

Answer (score -1):

About your USART1_IRQHandler, have you check if the interrupt is active with

```
__HAL_RCC_UART4_CLK_ENABLE();
HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(USART1_IRQn, 0, 0);
HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
```

and if you enable it with this call

```
UART_Receive_IT( &huart1 );
```

I am using STM32Cube, repository V1.25.0.

Now, about your code inside the USART1_IRQHandler(), you could use shortcut to handle what you want to do. If I understand, you have 4 leds to control with the Timer4 and 4 channels.

The pulse is the Output Compare value (TIM4->CCR1 for channel 1). So, I would start the timer with a pulse equal to the Period (or zero. See note below).

From that point, if you want to change the brightness, you have just to change the pulse width with

```
__HAL_TIM_SET_COMPARE( htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_1, pwm_value);
```

or with

```
TIM4->CCR1 = pwm_value;
```

You could also disable any channel with

```
__HAL_TIM_DISABLE_IT( htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
__HAL_TIM_ENABLE_IT( htim4, TIM_CHANNEL_1);
```

So, you get something like that

```
if(i == '1'){
    TIM4->CCR1 = pwm_value;
} else if(i == '2')  {
    TIM4->CCR1 = pwm_value;
    TIM4->CCR2 = pwm_value;
} ...
```

Note: I don't know how are connected your leds. If the led is connected to Vcc and the other end to the MPU pin, a LOW pulse will turn ON the led and HIGH pulse will turn it OFF.

Comment: ı use LEDS on board PD12,PD13,PD14,PD15

Comment: @FurkanGüngör - Could it be that you are driving the PWM parameters at an unsuitable range of duty cycles? It could be that the range is chosen so that the human eye wouldn't notice a difference in LED brightness. This however, is not a programming topic (and off-topic for StackOverflow) - apart from requirement analysis is part of SW development... :)

Comment: I fixed my error and its work good.And brightness changing notice prominently.Also made a video about this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPRcU8bLo24 also ı write  a blog about this project also ı explain the code there in turkish but you can see source code there below.